# Slew Rate Controlled GPIO

Tags: gpio, slew-rate

What is the purpose or advantage of using Slew Rate controlled output capability for GPIOs?

Comment: Slew rate control limits the production of high frequency components in a transition and reduces the potential 'noise' produced by any given circuit. This becomes ever more important as PCB track length get longer or you transition in wires to go offboard.

Comment: @JackCreasey, that's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Photon ...so be it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slew rate control limits the production of high frequency components in a transition and reduces the potential 'noise' produced by any given circuit. This becomes ever more important as PCB track length gets longer or you transition into wires to go offboard.